# Portable virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Portable virtualization software?](https://superuser.com/questions/82411/portable-virtualization-software)

Is there a portable version of virtual box, or any similar software that can run other os in a windows system?

Comment: Here's another dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/82411/portable-virtualization-software